# Enforcing UNIQUE KEY only on active devices mySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, create-table, alter-table

How does one go about enforcing a UNIQUE KEY within a database that applies only in certain conditions? For a specific example the table consists of several columns which must remain unique only when another BIT column is set.

Simply adding the BIT column to the key is insufficient as there could be several retired devices of the same configuration.

This seems such a prevalent use case, surely there are several work-arounds if no inbuilt capability?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: What you're looking for is called a `filtered index` or a `conditional index`, which isn't a feature that MySQL supports, AFAIK. Here's a [workaround](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43/how-to-create-a-conditional-index-in-mysql), though.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 is my version @GMB.

I'm hoping GMBs solution works, no luck there yet unfortunately. Thanks for your input EricBrandt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a partial unique key. The solution in MySQL varies depending on your version.

In MySQL 8.0:

```
create table mydevices (
    id int primary key,
    device_id int,
    location_id,
    is_active tinyint(1),
    unique key (device_id, location_id, nullif(is_active, 0))
);
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `null` values are ignored when checking unique constraint. So the above allows duplicates on device_id / location_id when is_active is 0, while forbidding them when is_active is 1.

Comment: Thanks mate! Some corrections to be made before that example works but their minor details. Minor details that did take me a good bit of thinking over but I worded it out and its been tested to be working.

Comment: create table mydevices (
    id int primary key,
    device_id int,
    location_id int,
    is_active tinyint(1),
    unique key (device_id, location_id, (nullif(is_active, 0)))
);

Answer (score 2):

MySQL supports computed columns now.  So, you can use that:

```
alter table t
    add unq_column as (case when bitcol = 1 then othercol end);

create unique index unq_t_bit_othercol on t(unq_column);
```

This uses the feature of MySQL that it allows duplicates for `NULL` in unique indexes.

Comment: Definitely works so thanks for that, in my case however creating the additional column is unnecessary when I can do the same in the key as per the above answer. There would be use cases I'm sure where this would be beneficial.